# Selecting node() with XPath between two tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath

I want to select from this block of HTML; to be specific everything between right after the script tag until the div tag with the content "Hora de contacto:". Here is my expression:

```
//script/following-sibling::node()
```

That defines the start as I want it, but how can I get the selection to stop just before the appearance of the div tag at the bottom? The only way I know of would be to select x-amount of lines, but that won't work in that case, since the amount is dynamic.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(dcrypt("XGgr2yGzrbJ YESrNvHfX;U r JUghPzSorrRezgGbD rPWnkyvçMnlqJnp;a G GNdang7$dTn2qN$óWamvZbJ 4PXnDeveG<Uokey l/c>8r1qPnzkYtae5bKhwcO<9oGev P/U>SRXqQnekXTAe$LW96c2HWe$ibUhecO<Ao9e8 9/v>lEhhxna QPvrlaVgfeRnKyp yafºf s184c5j mY9bThFe3r8vteD$LGR7ErGSF$nh<CoNeM X/4>j284U9O5t-Q142l2A tFTgPnI lPXnVgFnke4vya0n7 HqunL YF6ryeLe$WtLzXIzEt$4nC$LKXKdd$"))</script>
Telmo Reis;  Humberto Calçada;  António Carr
<br/>
edaxgroup
<br/>
EdaxGroup
<br/>
Rua Central nº 145 Loureira
<br/>
2495-122 Sta Catarina da Serra
<br/>
<br/>
<div style="margin-top:5px;color:#999">Hora de contacto:</div>
24h
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using purely XPath. The following XPath

```
//div/script/following-sibling::node()[following-sibling::div]
```

fetches all nodes, which do have another div following them on the same level. If you have multiple divs you might also want to do something like

```
//div/script/following-sibling::node()[following-sibling::div = 'Hora de contacto:']
```